# Getting a value at multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataframe below that is all about companies expenses. Is there a way to get the charge details for particular location at the specific date. Let me explain in detail below (may be this is one of the toughest problem to solve)

```
   df <- structure(list(Location = c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L1", "L2", "L3"
    ), Day = c("05/13/2018", "05/13/2018", "05/13/2018", "05/14/2018", 
    "05/14/2018", "05/14/2018"), `Lab Charge` = c(18, 12, 22, 
     14, 11, 11), `Elec Charge` = c(19, 14, 16, 20, 14, 14), 
  `Mach Charge` = c(19, 22, 16, 15, 15, 15)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

     df
     Location      Day       Lab Charge  Elec Charge  Mach Charge
      L1           05/13/2018   18       19           19
      L2           05/13/2018   12       14           22
      L3           05/13/2018   22       16           16
      L1           05/14/2018   14       20           15
      L2           05/14/2018   11       14           15
      L3           05/14/2018   12       14           15
```

At each locations (L1,L2 and L3) there are 2 dates (May 13 and May 14). Well. I need at Location L1, at minimum lab charge(that is 14, because among May 13 and May 14, the minimum was 14) what was Elec Charge and Mach Charge. Similarly I need at Location L1,at minimum Elec Charge( that is 19) what was Lab charge and Mach Charge. So for each location I need this details. Can we solve this? Looks like it is complicated

Comment: Yes I did not. Actually I accept the answers at the last so it is delayed. Apologies

Comment: Please post your data using the dput() function.

Comment: I did add now :)

Comment: @DevP  Can you show the expected output

Comment: Actually I thinking on How can we show in a output. There is no expected output. But the output should be based on my logic that I explained

Comment: That is strange.  You meant there is  no expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to restate your problem.
   For each location: 
      On the day with the lowest lab charge, what were the elec and mach charges?
      On the day with the lowest elec charge, what were the lab and mach charges?

First, R doesn't like names with spaces, so I will rename them.

```
library(tidyverse) 

df <- df %>% 
  rename(LabCharge = `Lab Charge`, 
         ElecCharge = `Elec Charge`, 
         MachCharge = `Mach Charge`)
```

Then, we will add a flag to each day that is the minimum charge.

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Location) %>% 
  mutate(min_lab = LabCharge == min(LabCharge, na.rm = TRUE),
         min_elec = ElecCharge == min(ElecCharge, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Finally, we want to limit to these minimum rows. The `min_lab` and `min_elec` variables are `booleans` that are either true or false. By filtering on the variable, we see only those rows where the variable is `TRUE`, that is, only the records for the lab where the specified charge is at its minimum.

```
df %>% filter(min_lab)

df %>% filter(min_elec)
```

You will see in this solution that location 2 has two days with the same electric charge, so they are both flagged as the minimum and both reported.

Comment: Happy to help. If this is the best answer to your question feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we need a group by `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Location) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with('Charge')), min, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Akrun, I see you have taken columns 3 to 5. Actually it should be within the same column. FOr example Lab Charge minimum at L1 is 14.  Because Lab charge is occuring twice at May 13 and May 14 so. It is not between 3 to 5 columns

Comment: @DevP  Not, it is not taking between columns.  It is looping on each column separately